# How to successfully publish a KMM library on localMaven() for android project to consume it?

Tags: android, maven, gradle, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile, kmm

I'm trying to integrate KMM library I made with my Android project. Till now I've successfully published the KMM library locally by following the steps [here](https://dev.to/kotlin/how-to-build-and-publish-a-kotlin-multiplatform-library-creating-your-first-library-1bp8)

But unfortunately when trying to add it as a dependency in my Android project the project doesn't build:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugNativeLibs'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.example.kmm:core-android:1.0.0-snapshot.1.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/example/kmm/core-android/1.0.0-snapshot.1/core-android-1.0.0-snapshot.1.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/example/kmm/core-android/1.0.0-snapshot.1/core-android-1.0.0-snapshot.1.pom
 Required by:
     project :app
```

I've already added `mavenLocal()` to my repositories

```
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}
```

But still getting nothing, any help ?

Note: when trying to consume the library in another KMM project or Module it successfully builds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a trivial mistake
I was trying to add `mavenLocal()` repository to the project `build.gradle` file when I was supposed to add it to the `settings.gradle` file which obviously overrides the repositories declared in the `build.gradle`

Answer (score 2):

By default, no artifacts of an Android library are published. To publish artifacts, you need to add below config in your gradle file.

```
    kotlin {
        android {
            publishLibraryVariants("release", "debug")
        }
    }
```

Please check here for the details:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/mpp-publish-lib.html#publish-an-android-library

Comment: I already made that setup for the KMM project Gradle file and it's working great with other KMM projects.